# Translating this curl line to Rails Post Request and returning JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, request, response

I've posted a few related questions to this, but I'm still a bit lost in getting the implementation.

Essentially I need to translate this line from the Venmo API for making payments:

```
curl https://api.venmo.com/v1/payments -d access_token=4e4sw1111111111t8an8dektggtcbb45 -d email="someemail@gmail.com" -d amount=5 -d note="Delivery."
```

into my Rails site in a POST request form/format.

I have the following in my View right now for the form:

```
<!-- Venmo box -->
                    <div class="box box-warning">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <%= form_tag ('/make_payment_path') do %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag "access_token", @access_token %>
                          <h3 class="box-title">Pay Bill using Venmo Account</h3>
                            <div id="payment_note_input">
                            <%= text_field_tag "payment_note", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "add a note to your payment" %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="payment_target_input">
                                <%= text_field_tag "payment_target", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "pay an email address" %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="payment_amount_input">
                                <%= text_field_tag "payment_amount", nil, class:"form-control", placeholder: "enter the payment amount!"%>
                            </div>
                                </br>
                        <%= submit_tag "Make payment", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
```

And the following in my Dashboard controller that corresponds to the view:

```
def make_payment_path
if !params[:access_token].nil?

    uri = URI.parse("https://api.venmo.com/v1/payments")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"access_token" => params[:access_token], "email" => params[:payment_target],
     "amount" => params[:payment_amount], "note" => params[:payment_note]} )

    response = http.request(request)
end
end
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction here? Once this POST request is processed through Venmo, it should return a JSON response, as seen [here](https://developer.venmo.com/docs/quickstart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what the error message is. :-)

I ran your code and the response.body had "400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Looks like you need to force SSL with:

```
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

**Example:**

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
```

New code gets a json response:

```
{"error": {"message": "You did not pass a valid OAuth access token.", "code": 261}}
```

Assume adding in the correct access token will resolve the issue.

*As a side note, you might also want to move the controller code into a Model*

Comment: I'm confused on this portion of the code: `<%= form_tag ('/make_payment_path') do %>`

Because when I test it, it requires a route for make_payment_path. Should this form even be creating a route?

Comment: Yep, you need a route. routes.rb is just a traffic controller, it directs you to the right controller. In this case without a route Rails doesn't know to send the /make_payment_path to the make_payment_path action of the dashboard controller. Assuming your controller is called Dashboard, this route should do it:  
post 'make_payment_path' => 'dashboard#make_payment_path'    

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Okay, I added a correct route as you mentioned above, and now have it working by adding `redirect_to :action => :confirm_payment` to the bottom of the make_payment_path action in the Dashboard controller.

How do I render the JSON response now from the Venmo API?

Comment: `render json: response.body` is what I was looking for here. I think I've got the rest of it. Thanks for the help!